# Manually authenticate a user for a specific subdomain in Symfony 5

Tags: symfony

I need to redirect the user after successful registration to their own subdomain (test for this example).

```
/**
 * @Route("/signup", name="app_signup", host="admin.mysymfony.local")
 */
public function signup(
    Request $request, 
    UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder,
    LoginFormAuthenticator $authenticator, 
    GuardAuthenticatorHandler $guardAuthenticatorHandler
): Response
{
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(SignupType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $user = $form->getData();
        $user->setPassword($passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPassword()));
        $roles = $user->getRoles();
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_ADMIN';
        $user->setRoles($roles);
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();
        $this->get('session')->set('user_id', $user->getId());

        return $guardAuthenticatorHandler->authenticateUserAndHandleSuccess(
            $user,          
            $request,
            $authenticator, 
            'main'          
        );
    }

    return $this->render('security/signup.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

This works fine and the user is redirected to this method after successful authentication:

```
/**
 * @Route("/signup/complete", name="app_signup_complete", host="admin.mysymfony.local")
 */
public function signupComplete(
    Request $request, 
    UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder,
    LoginFormAuthenticator $authenticator, 
    GuardAuthenticatorHandler $guardAuthenticatorHandler
): Response
{
    if ($this->getUser() && $this->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN') ) {
        error_log('User authenticated');// this is logged successfully
    }
    if ( strpos($request->getHost(), 'admin.') == 0 ) {

        $host = str_replace('admin.', 'test.', $request->getHost()); 
        $homeUrl = $this->generateUrl('app_home');
        $testHomeUrl = $request->getScheme() . '://' . $host. $homeUrl;

        return $this->redirect(
            $testHomeUrl            
        );
    }
}
```

This is the method that is called after redirection to the user subdomain:

```
/**
 * @Route("/home", name="app_home")
 */
function index(MessageGenerator $messageGenerator) {
    if ( $this->getUser() && $this->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        $message = $messageGenerator->getHappyMessage();
        $htmlResponse = '<html><body>';
        $htmlResponse .= "<p>Lucky message: ".$message. '</p>';
        $htmlResponse .= "<p>User id : {$this->getUser()->getId()}."
            . '</p>';        
        $htmlResponse .= "<p>Is granted ROLE_USER : {$this->isGranted('ROLE_USER')}."
            . '</p>';
        $htmlResponse .= "<p>Is granted ROLE_ADMIN : {$this->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')}." 
            . '</p>';            
        $htmlResponse .= '</body></html>';
        return new Response(
            $htmlResponse
        );
    }
    else {
        return new Response(var_export($this->get('session')->get('user_id'), true));
    }
}
```

As expected it falls in the else section and the value of user_id passed to the session is not recognized because it is a different subdomain. 
All suggestions are welcome and please if there is something that needs clarification let me know.

Comment: you maybe have a typo? `$this->isGranted['ROLE_ADMIN']` the `[]` should be `()`, no?

Comment: @Jakumi, Typo corrected. Thank you!

Comment: is this running on the same domain? in any case, you should obviously set the cookie for the main domain https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain ... you probably have to look up how to do this in symfony, but I'm pretty sure it's in the security config https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#cookie-domain